# How to get the JobID for the airflow dag runs?

Tags: python, pyspark, airflow

When we do a dagrun, on the Airflow UI, in the "Graph View" we get details of each job run.

**JobID is something like "scheduled__2017-04-11T10:47:00"**.

I need this JobID for tracking and log creation in which I maintain time each task/dagrun took.

So my question is **how can i get the JobID within the same dag that is being run**.

Thanks,Chetan

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This value is actually called `run_id` and can be accessed via the context or macros.

In the python operator this is accessed via context, and in the bash operator this is accessed via jinja templating on the `bash_command` field.

More info on what's available in macros:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/macros.html

More info on jinja:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#jinja-templating

```py
from airflow.models import DAG
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator


dag = DAG(
    dag_id='run_id',
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2017, 2, 26)
)

def my_func(**kwargs):
    context = kwargs
    print(context['dag_run'].run_id)

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='python_run_id',
    python_callable=my_func,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
    )

t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='bash_run_id',
    bash_command='echo {{run_id}}',
    dag=dag)

t1.set_downstream(t2)
```

Use this dag as an example, and check the log for each operator, you should see the `run_id` printed in the log.

Comment: does this only work for scheduled runs? I'm running from the CLI and get `kwargs['dag_run']` is None

Comment: works  on SSHOperator  as well :t3 = SSHOperator(
        dag=dag,
        ssh_conn_id='some-great-worker',
        task_id='666',
        command=f"""{{{{ run_id }}}}"""
    )

Comment: How to access it in SnowflakeOperator?