# Airflow Persistent Data Storage Across DAGs

Tags: airflow

I have a couple of DAGs that create temporary AWS EMR Clusters and then terminates them once they're finished running. I would like to create a new DAG that runs daily and generates a report of every EMR Cluster created for that day along with how long it ran and send this report to various people in an email.

I need to store the EMR Cluster ID value though so that my report generator has a list of every EMR Cluster ID for that day. I'm wondering if it's possible for me to modify an Airflow Variable to store this information e.g., I could have an Airflow variable where the key is "EMR_CLUSTERS" and the value is a JSON string with all the data I want to record. Or could I use the Airflow metadatabase that's already being used to write to a new table there where I can write this information?

What are my options for storing permanent data in Airflow?

Comment: Wouldn't it also be possible to create a simple DAG which queries the AWS API and asks for EMR Clusters created at a specific time - or with specific tags? Saving you time to recreate the meta data storage?

Answer (score 4):

Either of the options you mentioned would work:

1. Airflow Variable
2. Metadata DB

A **third option** would be network storage.
If you are running airflow distributed, then it's possible you are storing DAGs on network storage, and mounting it into the workers/scheduler/webserver. In which case, putting a file based report on this storage (and possibly emailing it out etc.) would be a solid bet.

[You could write a plugin](https://airflow.apache.org/plugins.html) that would work with any of these 3, and it could display what got written/sent when.

**Variables**

[Easily read/written](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#variables), but bit sloppy to overwrite it everyday IMO.

**MetadataDB**

Use [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) to create and read/write tables storing this information.
You can get a session on the airflow metadata DB by doing:

```py
from airflow import settings
session = settings.Session()
```

**Network Storage**

In this case just read/write files normally.

Comment: For the Variables option their documentation only demonstrates how to read from Variables not write them from within Python code. I know how to set them using the CLI like `airflow variable --set key value` but is it possible to set them from code (besides sending the previous command through a BashOperator)? I'm trying to find the `airflow.models.Variables` API documentation but having trouble finding it.

Comment: Also, I'm wondering if it's bad practice to use the MetaDB for this type of task? I feel like it would be infrastructure versus code mixture that could cause potential hazards. For example someone in DevOps could create a new MetaDB for the Airflow environment without realizing it's also used for code (idk just one example off the top of my head). I feel like there should be an Airflow standard for something common like this or maybe it's expected the users will create their own database to store information like this?

Comment: We use a lot of airflow and use the metadata DB for our own plugins. We have a custom executor as part of the plugins, and it creates the tables if they don't exist. If someone kills the whole airflow DB, then plugin data is probably not the biggest concern. A fourth option I thought of is just put the info into S3 (since you are using EMR, you prob have access to S3).

Comment: I thought about the S3 option and that's the option I'm leaning towards. But from my understanding of S3 there is no locking mechanism so I'm wondering if there could be a race condition if two of my workers go to record their EMR Cluster details on the JSON file contained in S3 at the same time.

Comment: I would write it so that each job wrote to a file/folder that had the run_id in it somewhere. This would keep it unique an avoid locking. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43345991/how-to-get-the-jobid-for-the-airflow-dag-runs)

Comment: Writing to a file would be a potential solution but I'm working on a clustered environment so that won't work. Your network storage idea is clever but we aren't using that to implement our clustered environment. We just put all the files on every server :/ your clustered environment sounds way cooler though (you have my interested in that lol).

Comment: The convoluted S3 solution would be to make the S3 JSON file appendable only by sending additions to a Lambda and having only the Lambda update the JSON. Then everything else would just be able to read from the S3 JSON file not write to it. But that's an expensive solution.

Comment: I think writing to a Variable is actually a very easy and clean way to go.   We used to update variables all the time when doing batch data dumps and tracking the latest last modified time of the data we'd dumped so we could continue from there on the next run.  Given though that you might have different jobs writing to the same variable you do run the risk of not transactionally writing the variables, so I might consider writing a different variable for each data that does this, and then separately have a dag that reads all those variables once a day and sends out a report.